# GStreamer Mac(OSX) avfvideosrc to RTMP issue (Getting Stuck at Redistribute Latency)

Tags: gstreamer, rtmp, gstreamer-1.0

I am trying to get gstreamer to stream video from avfvideosrc to RTMP. Its partially working.

Here is the command I am using

```
 gst-launch-1.0 -e avfvideosrc ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! flvmux streamable=true ! queue ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://<my-server>/my-stream/live'
```

The above command works but I am missing something

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
> Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
> Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
> New clock: GstSystemClock
> Redistribute latency...

It gets stuck at this point and till now on the server I have no logs. No attempt to make any connection. Once I press Ctrl-C

> ^Chandling interrupt.
> Interrupt: Stopping pipeline ...
> EOS on shutdown enabled -- Forcing EOS on the pipeline
> Waiting for EOS...
> Redistribute latency...
> Got EOS from element "pipeline0".
> EOS received - stopping pipeline...
> Execution ended after 0:00:06.339788000
> Setting pipeline to NULL ...
> Freeing pipeline ...

Interestingly once I press Ctrl-C it establishes connection starts streaming to the [MediaMTX server(https://github.com/bluenviron/mediamtx) and then processes EOF and closes down. The logs on the server at this point look like this

> Feb 06 04:08:18 ip-<private_ip> mediamtx[3516550]: 2024/02/06 04:08:18 INF [RTMP] [conn <mac_ip>:29605] opened
> Feb 06 04:08:18 ip-<private_ip> mediamtx[3516550]: 2024/02/06 04:08:18 INF [RTMP] [conn <mac_ip>:29605] is publishing to path 'my-stream/live', 1 track (H264)
> Feb 06 04:08:19 ip-<private_ip> mediamtx[3516550]: 2024/02/06 04:08:19 INF [RTMP] [conn <mac_ip>:29605] closed: EOF

It is clearly establishing the connection once I press Ctrl-C and tearing down because of EOF. I have tried executing the same command to publish to Youtube instead of my RTMP server and I see the same issue on client side.

However I am able to successfully publish the videotestsrc stream to my RTMP server using the command below

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e videotestsrc ! queue ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! flvmux streamable=true ! queue ! rtmpsink location='rtmp://<my-server>/my-stream/live'
```

The successful publish logs are as below

> Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
> Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
> Redistribute latency...
> Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
> Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
> Redistribute latency...
> New clock: GstSystemClock
> 0:00:44.8 / 99:99:99.

Appreciate in advance any help on the same issue.

Comment: SO is a programming Q&A platform and this question is not about programming. [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Please delete this.

Comment: If this is a programming question then I'm voting to close for not supplying a [mcve] which is required. You also need to tag this with whatever language you are using.

Comment: The commands I have given in the question are a proxy for the program and they are equivalent in the gstreamer framework. I have given one command which works and another command which doesn't work which can be easily reproduced. I have tagged with the issue with gstreamer tags and gstreamer give 2 interfaces CLI and APIs appropriately similar to other gstreamer issues on SO.